# Android emulator resolution, aliasing, gpu emulation

Tags: android, gpu, emulation, screen-resolution

I just downloaded the Android 4.1 (API 16) packages using the SDK Manager and created an Emulator for JellyBean. What I see now is everything on the JellyBean emulator is aliasing. When I open the screen capture dialog in DDMS, the screen is HUGE - I think the emulator is scaling that down, thus causing the aliasing. Screenshot:
[image: emulator vs ddms screen capture]

And here are the emulator settings:
[image: emulator settings]

I've used these same settings (minus the GPU emulation = yes) before for my ICS emulators, including the built-in screen resolution WXGA720. What settings should I change to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `Scale display to real size` is unchecked in the Launch Options dialog (which appears after clicking on Start... in the AVD manager).

[image: Launch options dialog]

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. I've never had to check this box when using my ICS emulators. This just  gives me control over how much it scales down; it doesn't fix the fact that it's scaling down from some massive size.

Comment: Could you try the following in a terminal?
`telnet localhost 5554`
`window scale 1`
`quit`
Just to see if it works.

Comment: That makes the emulator gigantic, which I guess gets rid of the aliasing :) Now to get it back to a size that fits on my screen...

Comment: Afaik, the size of the phone's screen can only be changed by selecting a different skin or providing a custom resolution. If I understand your question and responses correctly, you want to keep the current skin and window size, but get rid of the aliasing issue. I'm afraid that the aliased pixels are rather the result of a bug, not a missing configuration. At least, I was not able to find any config options for that. I suggest filling a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) and turning off GPU emulation OR selecting a different skin until it gets fixed.